# Guest can reach host but host can't reach guest on Virtualbox Host Only network

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, virtualbox

I am trying to run an Ubuntu Server 16.04 guest in an Ubuntu 15.10 host with Host Only networking in VirtualBox. I am aware there are few questions with similar problems, their configuration isn't quite the same as mine and I'm still stuck after reading them.

The guest can ping and fetch data from both the host and external websites.

**The host cannot ping the guest or connect to any web service running on the guest.**

I am following [these instructions](http://christophermaier.name/blog/2010/09/01/host-only-networking-with-virtualbox) with some details changed.

## In VirtualBox

One Host-Only network created, `vboxnet0` with address `192.168.100.0` and network mask `255.255.255.0`.

Guest has NAT for adapter 1 (default setting) and `vboxnet0` as adapter 2.

## On the Host

```
#> ifconfig vboxnet0
vboxnet0  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 0a:00:27:00:00:00
      inet addr:192.168.100.0  Bcast:192.168.100.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
```

## On the Guest

This is `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# Host-only interface
# vboxnet0 Host Only Adapter has address 191.168.100.0
# guest has address 192.168.100.1
auto enp0s8
iface enp0s8 inet static
        address         192.168.100.1
        netmask         255.255.255.0
        network         192.168.100.0
        broadcast       192.168.56.255

# NAT interface
auto enp0s3
iface enp0s3 inet dhcp
```

The interface names are not `eth0` etc, apparently this is due to kernel evolution and it should be fine.

After a reboot, this is `ifconfig`

[image]

This seems to show the correct inet addr for `enp0s8` (which is the Host Only adapter), and `enp0s3` is NAT which appears to be working.

If I run `route`

[image]

I don't know how to interpret this exactly, but for some reason it lists `192.168.100.0` instead of `192.168.100.1`, which is what `ifconfig` and `/etc/network/interfaces` have.

**EDIT** in an earlier version of this question, the static IP of the guest wasn't within the netmask range of the Host Only adapter. Then, `ping` seemed to hang, now `ping 192.168.100.1` from the host produces

```
PING 192.168.100.1 (192.168.100.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.100.0 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
```

What's wrong? Thanks.

Comment: I imagined `192.168.200.1` would be reachable because of the existence of vboxnet0, that's it's raison d'etre (I have not idea why it's `.0` in `route`). And I have no idea what you mean about the netmask, `196.168.100.0` is supposed to be the gateway, I believe.

Comment: Apologies if I was unclear. To rephrase, why do you think I would want `192.168.100.2` as the address? The scheme I'm going for is `192.168.100.n` is the nth machine, with n starting from 1, so far there's only one machine (guest).

Comment: I managed to figure out what was wrong but you're really being incredibly unhelpful. You basically just scorned me for knowing less than you while giving no insight into *why* any of the above is wrong. Please take a moment to reflect on how that comes across in a community designed for helping people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It started working when I changed `vboxnet0` to have an IP address of `192.168.100.254` instead of `192.168.100.0`.

Answer (score 0):

192.168.100.0 is a reserved IP address for the network (when the mask is 255.255.255.0)

Change the host address (192.168.100.100 or 192.168.100.2)